# How to match DataFrame index and column against dictionary key and multiple values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary-comprehension

How can I modify the below dictionary comprehension to take into account that column `s` should also be a matching criteria?

```
import pandas as pd 

dct = {'NNI' : pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
                             'count': [13, 11, 10,12, 16]},
                            index =['2007-07-13', '2019-09-18', '2016-08-01', '2021-04-05','2017-01-04' ]),
       'NVEC' : pd.DataFrame({'s': [-1, -1, -1, 1, 1],
                              'count': [12, 10, 9,14,5]},
                             index =['2012-10-09', '2018-10-01', '2022-02-01', '2020-03-20','2016-04-06'])
      }

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2022-02-14', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14', '2022-02-14'], 
                   's': [-1,-1,-1,1,1], 
                   'count': [10, 10, 10, 9, 9]}, 
                  index = ['NNI', 'NVEC', 'IPA', 'LYTS', 'MYN'])
```

`df`:

```
            Date  s  count
NNI   2022-02-14 -1     10
NVEC  2022-02-14 -1     10
IPA   2022-02-14 -1     10
LYTS  2022-02-14  1      9
MYN   2022-02-14  1      9
```

`dct`:

```
{'NNI':       s  count
 2007-07-13  -1     13
 2019-09-18  -1     11
 2016-08-01  -1     10
 2021-04-05   1     12
 2017-01-04   1     16,

 'NVEC':      s  count
 2012-10-09  -1     12
 2018-10-01  -1     10
 2022-02-01  -1      9
 2020-03-20   1     14
 2016-04-06   1      5}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
df = df.assign(ratio=pd.Series({k: v['count'].gt(df.loc[k, 'count']).sum() / 
v['count'].ge(df.loc[k, 'count']).sum() for k,v in dct.items()})).fillna(0)

df
            Date  s  count     ratio
NNI   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.800000
NVEC  2022-02-14 -1     10  0.666667
IPA   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.000000
LYTS  2022-02-14  1      9  0.000000
MYN   2022-02-14  1      9  0.000000
```

Desired result is:

```
df
            Date  s  count     ratio
NNI   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.666667
NVEC  2022-02-14 -1     10  0.500000
IPA   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.000000
LYTS  2022-02-14  1      9  0.000000
MYN   2022-02-14  1      9  0.000000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add it as boolean mask like:

```
v.loc[v['s'] == df.loc[k, 's'], 'count']
```

So the code becomes:

```
df = df.assign(ratio=pd.Series({k: v.loc[v['s'] == df.loc[k, 's'], 'count'].gt(df.loc[k, 'count']).sum() / 
                                v.loc[v['s'] == df.loc[k, 's'], 'count'].ge(df.loc[k, 'count']).sum() 
                                for k,v in dct.items()})).fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
            Date  s  count     ratio
NNI   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.666667
NVEC  2022-02-14 -1     10  0.500000
IPA   2022-02-14 -1     10  0.000000
LYTS  2022-02-14  1      9  0.000000
MYN   2022-02-14  1      9  0.000000
```

Just a suggestion but it might be helpful to use a helper function here because the division is kind of unreadable there especially after adding the indexing. You could use:

```
def get_ratio(df_row, v):
    msk = v['s'] == df_row['s']
    numerator = v.loc[msk, 'count'].gt(df_row['count']).sum()
    denominator = v.loc[msk, 'count'].ge(df_row['count']).sum()
    return numerator / denominator

df = df.assign(ratio = pd.Series({k: get_ratio(df.loc[k], v) for k,v in dct.items()})).fillna(0)
```